# Legend is not properly scaled after exported image is resized

Tags: r, plot, legend

I am looking to understand why the legend on my plot is being altered when I resize the width of the plot, and how I can prevent this. Currently, I am using R.

The code I am using is this:

```
matplot(Year, AR4.Data[1:30,2:10], type=c("o"), pch=1, col=colorscheme, lwd=2)
legend(1998.5, 35, legend = AR4.Data[1:9,49], col=colorscheme, pch=1, cex=0.8)
```

Before altering the image width, the plot looks as follows:

[image: Before Altering]

After changing the width to 1400px, the output of the image is this:

[image: After Altering]

Is there a way to ensure that the legend size is minimized when the plot width is maximized?

Comment: If you intend to export a plot, optimize it for a device with dimensions you state explicitly. Usually you use `pdf` or `png`.

Comment: The images attached are png. I'm looking for a way to ensure the size of the legend remains at the same scale before and after altering the width.

Comment: I think Roland is saying that you shouldn't be altering size after export; set the width in the `png` device when you export, instead.

Comment: Yes, please read `help("png")`.